# What can I use instead of buttons in the JPanel to get the same appearance in all OS?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, cross-platform, jpanel

I need to generate a rectangular grid (let say 3 by 4) consisting of squares of different colors. Moreover, the squares (cells of the grid) have to contain same short text. At the moment I solve the problem using buttons as elements of the grid. In more details, I have the following code:

```
JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nColumns));
fieldPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(nColumns*cellSize, nRows*cellSize));
for (int i=1; i<=nRows; i++) {
   for (int j=1; j<=nColumns; j++) {
      JButton btn = new JButton("<html><span style='color:#000000; font-size: 11pt;'>" + label + "</span></html>");
      btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellSize, cellSize));
      btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
      btn.setBackground(col);
      fieldPanel.add(btn);
   }
}
```

This approach has a disadvantage. I see buttons of different colors on Windows 7, but they are gray in Windows XP. To solve this problem I set the look and feel manually:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
```

But this also cause problems. It change the appearance of the main software that calls my program (my program is a part of a "big" software).

So, I want to solve the problem radically. I want to replace buttons by something else. And I think that the most stable solution (that guaranty the same appearance in all operating systems is to use images as background for the cell of the grid (images of monotonic colors)). But than I need to have a way to put labels on top of the images.

Can anybody, please, tell me how it can be done?

Comment: What are you setting the background to?

Comment: @jzd, I want my cell to have different colors. And to make it robust with respect to change of OS, I want to put images in my cell (for example red color as an image).

Comment: I was asking about your code: `btn.setBackground(col);`  What is col? Where is it defined?    I guess I don't see the issue with the different look and feels?

Comment: @jzd, col is color (`Color`). For example `col = Color((int) 100, (int) 100, (int) 100)`.

Answer (score 3):

> But than I need to have a way to put labels on top of the images.

You can display the text centered over the image by using:

```
label.setIcon(...);
label.setText("Text over Image");
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

Or you can use one of the suggestions from the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) entry.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the most stable solution … is to use images as background…

Another approach is to implement the `Icon` interface, as seen in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979) that also demonstrates a variation on @camickr's suggestion. The result is versatile text placement and stringent control over painting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this example

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelBG {
    JFrame f;
    public PanelBG() {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        int nRows = 3;
        int nColumns = 4;
        int cellSize = 50;
        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
        fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(nRows, nColumns));
        fieldPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(nColumns*cellSize, nRows*cellSize));
        Color colors[]={
                new Color(115, 114, 83),
                new Color(120, 130, 83),
                new Color(140, 140, 83),
                new Color(160, 180, 83),
                new Color(170, 190, 83),
                new Color(80, 190, 73),
                new Color(100, 120, 83),
                new Color(150, 240, 83),
                new Color(180, 150, 83),
                new Color(210, 190, 83),
                new Color(230, 11, 83),
                new Color(255, 255, 255)
        };
        for (int i=1; i<=nRows; i++) {
           for (int j=1; j<=nColumns; j++) {
              //JButton btn = new JButton("<html><span style='color:#000000; font-size: 11pt;'>"
              //        + label.getText() + "</span></html>");
              //btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellSize, cellSize));
              //btn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
              //btn.setBackground(new Color(54,36,5));
              //fieldPanel.add(btn);
               JPanel p = new JPanel();
               p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellSize, cellSize));
               JLabel l = new JLabel("Jlabel");
               p.add(l);
               p.setBackground(colors[i*j-1]);
               fieldPanel.add(p);
           }
        }
        f.getContentPane().add(fieldPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PanelBG();
    }
}
```